# jQuery ajax() preloading multiple things

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloading

I am using the following code to preload an mp3:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "boom.mp3",
    success: function() {
        //done
    }
});
```

Is there anyway I can have multiple elements preloaded (images and mp3 for example)?

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "boom.mp3", "moo.jpg",
    success: function() {
        //done
    }
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: In the last code block, did you mean `url: ["boom.mp3", "moo.jpg"],`?

Comment: @rxgx: I think this is purely an example of what the OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.5, there are two new ways to handle this: deferred and promises.

[Creating Responsive Applications Using jQuery Deferred and Promises](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg723713.aspx)

```
function successFunc(){
  console.log( “success!” );
}    

function failureFunc(){
  console.log( “failure!” );
}

$.when(
  $.ajax( "/main.php" ),
  $.ajax( "/modules.php" ),
  $.ajax( "/lists.php" )
).then( successFunc, failureFunc );
```

To use this in your instance, for example, just replace the `ajax` requests with `load`.

Answer (score 2):

An idea from me: Collect all filenames in an array and loop through the array. Save th received opjects in another array and use it for what you want.

Perhaps it will work if you define the object in the url parameter, seperated by colon.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:'',
    dataType:'json',
    async:false,
    beforeSend:function(data){ // Are not working with dataType:'jsonp'
      $('#content').html('Loading...');
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('#content').html(data.content);
    }
});
</script>
```

Read [beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: So, I read that... What is it that you are saying exactly? That I have to run another `ajax()` request in "beforeSend"? That seems woefully inadequate.

Comment: i m just displaying the text `loading..`. untill ajax is completed

Comment: Yes you are, but that's not what my questions asks :)

Comment: first of all ur code is wrong `url: "boom.mp3", "moo.jpg",` is not for the preload thing. `url` is A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

Comment: I know, that was an example - hence the e.g. : )

Comment: Forgive me for voting down an answer that didn't answer my question. Turns out I'm not the only one... :/